# how to enable Wi-Fi and search for networks on windows phone emulator

Tags: networking, wifi, emulation, windows-phone-8.1

Can I enable wifi on my windows phone emulator? I want so see networks available in emulator like I see on a real mobile Phone. I am using VS 2013, and working on a laptop with wifi. When I click the on button on Wi-Fi settings it remains in a loop.
I already managed to give internet acces to my emulator. But I wish to search for wifi networks.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't enable WiFi on your Windows Phone Emulator because the emulator is actually a virtual OS running on Hyper-V, which is using your laptop WiFi connection for Windows Phone WiFi connection.

If you want to search for WiFi networks, you better search on a real device.