# How to simulate poor Wi-Fi on a Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: networking, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, wifi, emulation

I've been trying to review way of simulating a **poor** Wi-Fi signal on a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

When developing a Windows Phone 8 app, Visual Studio 2013 provided the [Simulation Dashboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206953(v=vs.105).aspx) within the **Tools** menu and looked to do exactly what I wanted:

[image]

The Simulation Dashboard now looks to have been replaced with the emulator **Additional Tools** for developing Windows Phone 8.1 apps:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above there is no **Wi-Fi** option for me to use.

I did have a thought that it might be because the Wi-Fi option is off within the emulator. I can't however turn it on and after a quick search found out why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753853/how-to-enable-wi-fi-and-search-for-networks-on-windows-phone-emulator) which makes sense.

What I would like to do if at all possible, is debug on the device itself and simulate poor Wi-Fi. I would have thought developers would want to test poor Wi-Fi when developing apps that rely on it.

Has anybody found a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases I have worked with the network simulation does exactly what you want to achieve via the Wi-Fi connection speed. Basically the network simulation means the Data connection as well as the Wi-Fi connection. It's more based on the speed of the incoming connection rather than the type of the connection(Data Connection or Wi-Fi). The question is do  you want to test the application on various network speeds or specific connection type(data connection or Wi-Fi). If you want to test it just on the network speed then I would advise you to use the network simulation and that'll provide you with very accurate results.